# Encode TIFF image using H.265 (HEVC) codec

Tags: video, tiff, hevc

Is it possible to encode image within TIFF file using HEVC codec?

Command:

> ./TAppEncoderStatic -i cubeImag.tif -wdt 1296 -hgt 1296 -cf 400 -fr 1 -f 1 -c ../cfg/encoder_intra_main_rext.cfg

But I am unable to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to re-encode a TIFF file using some HEVC native format, or do you want encode an image using HEVC and store the data stream inside a TIFF container? I guess both is possible, but at least the later will result in a non-standard TIFF that no standard TIFF decoder will understand AFAIK. But might be useful for internal/experimental storage.

Comment: I have one file .tif one image of one matriz , and a need used the HEVC to encode the file .tif . And i use the ./TAapEncoder for this. Last year i use the hevc for encode vídeos yuv, and this works good , but now i need use the codec hevc for one image and that image is .tif .

Comment: That is, I have a .tif image and want to encode it using the HEVC encoder. The output format can be bin , which is what the encoder offers .

Answer (score 1):

I believe TAppEncoderStatic is the JVM HEVC Reference Encoder. From what I remember, reference encoders expect the input to be in YUV format. In order to encode TIFF using HEVC codec, I recommend to do the following

1. Decode TIFF Image to YUV. You can use ffmpeg with the following command

   `ffmpeg -i input.tiff -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output.yuv`
2. Encode YUV using JVM Encoder.

Comment: Hello Friend,

first of all, thanks for the reply.

So what do you suggest is I spend tif image to yuv and code with the yuv?


But as I use an image in yuv, as yuv be a video and I just have a picture?

Comment: Having a picture is not a problem. YUV can be used for both image and video. When you have one frame of YUV, it can be used as an image. And when you have more than one frame, it will be a video. In your case, you can decode a picture to get one frame of YUV. You can use this frame of YUV as input to HEVC Video Encoder and generate one intra frame.